# vscode python no output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
print("hello")
```

Whatever I write in the python file, it only gives the current file path. How could I fix it?

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
Gangs-MacBook-Pro:yashirq gangzhao$ /usr/bin/python3 /Users/gangzhao/yashirq/Practice/Python/Grokking_Algorithms/Binary_Search.py
```

[image]

Comment: MacOS in the recent updates, replaces bash with zsh as the default shell in macOS. To switch to bash run : `exec bash`

Comment: I run `chsh -s /bin/zsh` as required. It doesn't work.

Comment: Run : `chsh -s /bin/bash` to set `bash` as the default / Run `chsh -s /bin/zsh` to set `zsh` as the default.

Comment: Changing default shell seems doesn't solve the problem. Still no output but only the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran this program in VS Code and it worked fine.

Just right click and select 'Run Python file in terminal' options. It should work!

[image: Run Python file in terminal]

[image: Sample Code]

Comment: I see `hello` as output in your VS Code console.

Comment: Yea, now it works. It's weird. I'm trying to close the post.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the file? You typically have to set up an [environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). If you want to just run a single python file and see the output in the integrated terminal, try right-clicking the editor, and clicking `Run Python File in Terminal`.

Comment: I'm running it in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the terminal.integrated.inheritEnv setting. I'm on ubuntu and had it set to false/unchecked. Toggling to true/checked brought back terminal functionality.